# Using only git commands, is there a way to find the latest commit that uses a tag with a specific pattern?

Tags: git

Part of my activities on my job is to do a bring-up from one Android OS version to another. To do that, we pick certain commits from the old OS branches to the new ones. More specifically, we move all the commits that were added after a certain tag (which represents a drop from another company) shows up on the log.

To make it easier to get those commits, I perform a `git log [tag-name]..HEAD --decorate --oneline`. However, it is quite normal to not know the name of the tag as it differs from branch to branch. All I know is that it starts with a very specific pattern (let's say "pd/US"). And as the command listed above only works if you have the full name of the tag, that does not work on the majority of cases.

So my question here is: is there a way for me to find the list of commits between the latest commit using that format of tag and the HEAD? It doesn't necessarily needs to be in one command. Even with multiple steps it would be welcomed.

I've actually tried a few things like getting a list of all the tags that contain that pattern by using `git tag -l "pd/US*"`. But as I need the most recent used, that didn't help much.

Other thing that I thought would help was using `git describe --abbrev=0`, as it shows the most recently used tag. But the project uses a lot of different tags, so it does not work as I wanted to...

Please feel free to ask for more details if I was not clear enough.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think git has a concept of "latest commit which uses a tag". A tag is a pointer to a specific commit which doesn't change. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging --- (Unless I'm misunderstanding you)

Comment: Indeed. Actually I'm not looking for a specific commit that have a tag (because I don't know the tag). I'm looking for the latest commit that have a tag starting with a given pattern. Then, list all the commits between that one and the HEAD.

Comment: What about `g tag -l 'pd/US*' --sort committerdate`? Hopefully the most recent commit will be at the bottom.

Comment: Tried it here but it did not work. Manually checking the git log, I've found the tag I'm looking for and, using you command, it appears in the middle of the list. Actually, I'm currently wondering if a `git log --decorate --oneline | grep "pd/US"` would work...

Comment: Note that the phrase *latest commit* can be interpreted in different ways. Each commit has two different date-and-time stamps—well, potentially different—for the author and committer, and each commit has a position in the commit graph. "Latest" could refer to the date and time stamps, or to the graph position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For visual spotting, `git log` has a `--decorate-refs` option :

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate-refs=refs/tags/pd/US*
git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate-refs=refs/tags/pd/US*
```

For a one stop command, `git describe` has a `--match` option :

```
git describe --tags --match=pd/US*
git describe --tags --match=pd/US* --abbrev=0
```